# Angular2 multiple dropdowns being affected by the same change

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm using Angular2 with javascript. Currently have a template in a TreeView component that looks something like this:

```
<li>
  <label style="color:red">{{block.toString()}}</label>
  <select aria-label="block menu" (change)="blockMenuSelected(block,$event)">
    <option value="COPY_BLOCK" select>copy</option>
    <option value="CUT_BLOCK">cut</option>
    <option value="DELETE_BLOCK">delete</option>
  </select>
</li>
<li *ngIf= "block.nextConnection && block.nextConnection.targetBlock()">
  <tree-view [block]="block.nextConnection.targetBlock()"></tree-view>
</li>
```

Notice that it's a recursive component. So there is a treeview component inside of a treeview component. The problem is that when I select something in the block menu dropdown, any other block menu dropdown on the page is also is affected by that selection event. I've tried giving each `<select>` element an unique id, but that hasn't changed anything. I'm not sure if this is an Angular2 bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It sounds like it might be event bubbling.  In `blockMenuSelected()` try calling `stopPropagation()` on the event.

Comment: Hm. It does sound like bubbling, but event.stopPropagation() is not resulting in a different output.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
blockMenuSelected(block, event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
   ...
}
```

ref https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2042

Comment: That isn't resolving the issue for some reason.

Comment: I think it might be angular updating the page and not event bubbling.

Comment: pass a unique id value and assign it to a variable(say ddown). Now add an ngIf to the select using this variable. if (ddown==id) then {}. Or you can place this logic within whatever function you invoke.